# referencing a list that is on parent web

Tags: list

The list "Region" exists at the parent web but the following code throws error. Is there anything else or other way I could reference a list that is on parent site?

```
SPList regionList = web.ParentWeb.GetList("Region");
```

Answer (score 2):

The `GetList` method of a web object requires a url to the list. 
Here's what intellisense says:

> Returns the list that is associated with the specified site-relative URL.
>   A string that contains the site-relative URL for a list, for example, /Lists/Announcements.

So in your case, you may want to change your code snippet like the following:

```
SPList regionList = web.ParentWeb.GetList("/Lists/Region");
```

Comment: I am going to try this method in few and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the SPWeb.GetList method uses a server-relative URL to get the list see here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlist.aspx).

You could add a using statement for the web and then get the list by it's name from the SPWeb.Lists collection:

```
Using (SPWeb web = web.ParentWeb)
{ SPList list = web.Lists["Region"]; }
```

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: I am going to try this method in few and let you know. Thanks